# Control size of iframe resize on click

Tags: javascript, iframe

This code is generated by 3rd party site, to embed a map. When the map is clicked, the iframe resizes to fill the entire browser viewport, and the header menu on my site is gone. Once that happens, there is no way to view the header menu on my site again.

Is there anyway to stop the entire view port being consumed by the map? I would like my site's header menu to remain visible.

I have been working with this line of code

oMap.style.height  = h + "px";

...but do not know enough to make progress

```
<p>My Header Menu</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vURL      = "http://maps.gsi.go.jp";
        var vURL_Site = "/?postmessage=1#5/35.362222/138.731389/&base=std&ls=std&disp=1&vs=c1j0l0u0f0";
        var oMap      = null;        
        function Init(){
            oMap = document.createElement("iframe");
            oMap.style.display = "none";
            oMap.src = vURL + vURL_Site;
            oMap.onload = function(){
                var oContent   = oMap.contentWindow;
                var ClientMode = {
                  baseUrl     : null
                , location    : null
                , LayerJS     : null
                , sakuzuList  : null
                , queryString : null
                };

                ClientMode.sakuzuList = [{"fileName":"","visible":true,"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"_markerType":"DivIcon","_html":"JAPAN"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[141.8115234375,37.47485808497102]}}]}];


                oContent.postMessage(ClientMode, vURL);

                EvtResize();
            };

            document.body.appendChild(oMap);
        };

        function EvtResize(){
            var w = window.innerWidth;
            var h = window.innerHeight;
            if(oMap != null){
                oMap.style.width   = w + "px";
                oMap.style.height  = h + "px";
                if(oMap.style.display == "none"){
                    oMap.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        };

        window.onload   = function(){
            document.body.style.margin   = "0px";
            document.body.style.padding  = "0px";
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

            Init();
        }
        window.onresize = EvtResize;
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried to emulate your problem in a JSFiddle, but instead of the header dissapearing, the iframe was truncated. This is due to `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"`,  which prevents scroll on the body element. You can play with the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/qbntskur/) to try to emulate your problem. It helps us out if you can provide working code that demonstrates the bug.

Answer (score 0):

The line `var h = window.innerHeight;` sets `h` equal to the the height of the  [inner window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight#Graphical_example) (in pixels). Then `oMap.style.height  = h + "px";` sets the iframe equal to that height.

From the code provided, it's not obvious why it causes your header to disappear. Rather, I would expect the iframe to be cut off, as it is appended below the header with `document.body.appendChild(oMap);`

If you want everything to fit on the screen, try subtracting the height of your header when setting the height for `oMap`. E.g., if your header is 200px tall, use `var h = window.innerHeight - 200;`.

Also, try removing the line `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";`. This prevents the `body` element from creating scrollbars when elements are too large to fit, and could be responsible for hiding your header.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know how to format the the amount of px, you helped with this var h = window.innerHeight - 200;

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can demonstrate the problem is using http://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/

Paste the above code, click on the map, the header disappears.

Then edit so that: oMap.style.height  = h - 40;

The header no longer disappears.

However on my live site this has caused another serious map display issue. Before I can proceed I will need to resolve a potentially related problem. So this one is on hold for now.